# Best way to check for results are received in Laravel

Tags: laravel-5

I'm looking for the best way to check or there is any results received from Laravel sql query. If I'm using only `$ads->isEmpty()`, it is a problem when query has not been executed, if the conditions for its execution do not meet.

If I'm using only `empty($ads)`, there is a problem when query has been executed but no results - it still gives blank value, so it is not empty anymore.

Maybe there is one, a better check, instead of these two?

```
if (Session::has('city')) {
    $ads = \App\Ad::orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();
}

if (empty($ads) or $ads->isEmpty()) {
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You *could* choose to always ensure `$ads` is a `Collection`.

E.g.

```
$ads = session()->has('city')
    ? \App\Ad::orderBy('id', 'desc')->get()
    : collect();

if ($ads->isEmpty()) {
    // ...
}
```

More information about

- [Ternary operators](https://davidwalsh.name/php-shorthand-if-else-ternary-operators)
- Session helper - [session()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/helpers#method-session)
- Collect helper - [collect()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/helpers#method-collect)

Comment: What do you mean? With the above code `$ads` would always be a Laravel `Collection`, either with or without items.

Comment: in my question $ads are in additional condition, if that condition does not meet, $ads will be null...

Comment: The `if (Session::has('city'))` ? That's still present in my code, but using a ternary operator instead.

Comment: yes. Oh, now I got it. If there is the only one way to achieve this, then adding additional condition looks more clear for me, as a newbie in Laravel :)

Comment: There are probably many ways to achieve what you're asking. This is one option. A [ternary is a PHP operator](https://davidwalsh.name/php-shorthand-if-else-ternary-operators), nothing to do with Laravel. And you can read more about [session()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/helpers#method-session) and [collect()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/helpers#method-collect).